# C# application unable to establish SSL/TLS connection

Tags: c#, security, ssl, networking, https

I have a c# application that generates an error "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel" when it tries to save a file to a remote SharePoint server.  This happens on a Windows 2012 server, but the application runs successfully from my desktop windows machine.

Also, from the dev server, I am able to connect to the SharePoint server with IE11, with only TLS 1.1 enabled.

The application has all security protocols enabled.

I also know that the application never calls the certificatevalidationcallback function.

Given these symptoms, does anyone have any idea what could be going wrong?

Comment: You might want to try connecting to your server using OpenSsl and enable verbose logging and see if that goes through successfully from the Windows 2012 Server.

Comment: After quite a bit of experimentation, I found the solution, but I'm still puzzled.  The solution turned out to be the use of 

System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls11;

which is not surprising.  What is surprising is that when I was getting the error, I was using 

System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

II thought there was no downside to allowing either protocol.

Answer (score 0):

After quite a bit of experimentation, I found the solution, but I'm still puzzled.  The solution turned out to be the use of

System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls11;

which is not surprising.  What is surprising is that when I was getting the error, I was using

System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

I specified both protocols because I wasn't sure which was being used by the remote server, and I thought there was no downside to allowing either protocol.

Now I'm wondering why allowing a second protocol causes the application to be unable to establish the secure channel.

Comment: there are two possibilities I can think of. One is that the web server is misbehaving and not negotiating a lower protocol. Some servers when presented with a TLS version they don't understand blow up instead of choosing a lower one. The second possibility is that TLS 1.2 is negotiated but a cipher suite couldn't be selected for TLS 1.2. For example, a client might say "RC4 can be used with TLS 1.1 or below" and the server only supports RC4.

Comment: Excellent suggestions: Thank You.